# How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?

Tags: python, pip

I recently need to install some packages

```
pip install future
pip install scikit-learn
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
```

I also tried by writin `sudo` before them but all it came up with the following errors in red lines:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 572, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 433, in _download_url
    for chunk in resp_read(4096):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 421, in resp_read
    chunk_size, decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 256, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 201, in read
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log'
```

Comment: I think it's network problem try `ping pypi.python.org` see if it works.
It can be solved with something as simple as restarting your router or reconnecting to your internet or even just trying again after sometime. please follow [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting here.

Comment: Avoid blindly using sudo to try magically try fix things when you aren't sure it's a permissions issue. It rarely will make things just work, but can mess up your permissions, which can cause you very annoying future issues. Only use sudo when you know it's needed.

Comment: If you are behind a firewall, it might be blocking file storage CDN sites.

Answer (score 358, accepted):

Use `--default-timeout=100` parameter with the install:

```
sudo pip install --default-timeout=100 future
```

Comment: Alternatively, I used `export PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100` since I had the `pip` command in a shared Dockerfile and it was a temporary requirement for me. But it works, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, It saves me in slow internet condition. I guess 100 is the the number of seconds pip'll wait for the reconnect after losing connection?

Comment: Can I make the timeout setting permament?

Comment: I cannot find the setting with `pip help` or `pip install help`. There is howerver `socket timeout`. I wonder what is the default value?

Comment: I cannot find the setting with `pip help` or `pip install help`. There is howerver `socket timeout`. I wonder what is the default value?

Comment: @Timo, use @Kerem's command (`export PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100`) in your `~/.profile` to make it permanent.

Comment: As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305112/pip-install-timeout-issue#comment117142274_61472212) by [asmaier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179014/asmaier) on [Pip Install Timeout Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50305112/1364007), the parameter may be `--timeout` rather than `--default-timeout`.

Comment: Another thing you can do in Docker is something like: `RUN python3 -m pip install --default-timeout=100 -r  /requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 42):

```
sudo pip install --default-timeout=100 future
```

or alternatively

```
export PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100
```

worked for me on Mac OS X

Answer (score 8):

They are two ways to handle this issue:

```
sudo pip install --default-timeout=100 future
```

or

```
pip install --default-timeout=100 future
```

Note: If you are not superuser of your machine, the `sudo pip` command will not work.

Comment: Note that it is not a good idea to use 'sudo' with pip. Use '--user' flag instead.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading `pip` solved the problem for me.

```bash
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the value of PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT (the value is an integer in seconds).

```
set PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=1200
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there to avoid any confusion, for pip3 you can use

```
sudo pip3 install --default-timeout=100 future
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that pip couldn't load a specific version of a package, which lead to the same error message i.e. `ReadTimeoutError`. Try to find the failing package and update it to the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using JetBrains PyCharm, the appropriate solution steps are :

1. connect to terminal/open terminal in PyCharm.
2. type `source <path to your projects environment eg: /users/name/myapp/venv>`
3. Run `pip install <package name>` or run `pip3 install <package name>` as per your installation

This will automatically install package for your interpreter.