# Cannot create Virtualenv in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm struggling with virtualenv in Python.

After `virtualenv _env` I get:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/marcin/Documents/Projects/django_tutorial/_env/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/marcin/Documents/Projects/django_tutorial/_env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/marcin/Documen...ial/_env/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-38.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (489kB)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 603, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 560, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/home/marcin/Documents/Projects/django_tutorial/_env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 432, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/marcin/Documents/Projects/django_tutorial/_env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 397, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/marcin/Documents/Projects/django_tutorial/_env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 312, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2375, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 724, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 922, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 817, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/marcin/Documen...ial/_env/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

I've got:

virtualenv 15.1.0

pip 9.0.1

Python 2.7.13

I'm out of ideas. I tried exporting locales, reinstalling pip, setuptools and virtualenv.
Do you have any suggestions? I will be grateful.

Comment: `ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.`. Are you able to access the site?

Comment: It's a timeout error. Might be a network issue. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port).

Comment: I set default timeout and I got the same error :(

Comment: I got very similar problem here, what I got is a 404 `HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/pkg-resources/`. However Ifound that there is no `simple/pkg-resources` directory under any mirror, so how may I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in China, you can change your `pip` source to solve this issue.

```
mkdir ~/.pip
echo '[global]' > ~/.pip/pip.conf
echo 'index-url = https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple' >> ~/.pip/pip.conf
```

By using the mirror of Tsinghua University, you might solve your problem.