# Cant install scipy through pip

Tags: python, scipy, pip

```
PS C:\Users\Marko> pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.0.8-cp36-none-win32.whl (26.0MB)
    22% |?  | 5.8MB 936kB/s eta 0:00:22Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 232, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 314, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 60, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\python\lib\http\client.py", line 449, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\python\lib\http\client.py", line 493, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\python\lib\socket.py”, line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\python\lib\ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\python\lib\ssl.py", line 871, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "c:\python\lih\ssl.py”, line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lio\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py”, line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File “c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=seif.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hasnes=hashes)
  File ”c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download .py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py”, line 603, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File “c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File ”c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File “c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File ”c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 560, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
```

I was trying to install scipy for python. I tried everything, reinstalled python and pip, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The picture is in the enter image description not sure if its supposed to be there, sorry first stackoverflow post.

Comment: You may want to review [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Also, modify your question tittle as such..cus it seems a downloading problem (first glance from the image) and not what you suggest now in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a timeout error. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port) may help.

For future posts, please read [the stack overflow posting guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, it's generally preferred to copy and paste the error rather than posting a screen shot so people can search through it more easily.

Comment: thank you so much, sorry about that just created the account. I'l familiarize myself with the site.

Comment: No problem! Another small note: If an answer solves your problem, it helps if you mark it as the correct solution (by clicking the tick below the answer voting arrows). In this case if my answer solves your problem, then this question is a duplicate so it will most likely be closed and accepting a solution doesn't matter too much, but for future questions it's good practice.