# Issue in installing Python 3 modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

My OS is Windows 10 and when I use pip command,encounter error below:
this error occurs during installing requests

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\naweed\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 302, in _error_catcher
File 
"c:\users\naweed\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\http\client.py", 
line 491, in readinto
n = self.fp.readinto(b)
File "c:\users\naweed\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\socket.py", 
line 589, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed 
out.
```

what's my problem?
how can fix it?
because of limitation in pasting all of error,I just showed short of it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port)

Answer (score 3):

Read timed out occurs if there is a network timeout in your requests by pip to download or discover a package
Here something to try

1. Take a network speed test and ensure good speed as well as latency
2. Open Run (Windows+R) then open resmon
3. Check for any processes with heavy usage
4. Open cmd as Administrator and try again

Comment: @naweed are you able to install any other packages especially small ones?

Comment: no,in every package i have errors and errors are same

Comment: there seems to be an error in python in connecting to the network, try to check for any firewall or reinstall python You may also try to do a network request from python console then try again

Comment: thanks, changed the network then the error has gone.