# I have problem running Telegram Bot with telepot

Tags: python, ssl, bots, telegram

I am creating a telegram bot using telepot, as I run this code, The following error comes :

My Code:

```
token = 'XXXXXXXX'
bot = telepot.Bot(token)
bot.getMe()
```

Error:

> Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)')

How to fix this error?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port?

Comment: @Pygirl I've successfully installed them; but i can't use .getMe() function !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to downgrade `urllib3` to `1.24.1`? See https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/issues/463#issuecomment-490874476