# Getting ReadTimeoutError for tensorflow while deploying python app to Azure Web App

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow-estimator, azure-webapps

```
remote: [20:44:36+0000] Collecting tensorflow==2.1.0

remote: [20:44:36+0000]   Downloading tensorflow-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (421.8 MB)

remote: ...............................................................

remote: ...

remote: .........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

remote: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by '    ("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/tensorflow-estimator/


remote: [20:51:54+0000] Collecting tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0

remote: ..........

remote:   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/18/90/b77c328a1304437ab1310b463e533fa7689f4bfc41549593056d812fab8e/tensorflow_estimator-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

remote: [20:52:09+0000]   Downloading tensorflow_estimator-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (448 kB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a slow connection to the server. Try increasing the timeout. check out the solution shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port):

Try:

```
sudo pip install --default-timeout=100 future
```

or

```
export PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100
```