# A problem with python. Console doesn't install module

Tags: python, pip

Today my python stopped working. I type in cmd `pip install watchdog` and get the errors(I wanna install some modules):

> ERROR: Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
>       yield
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 507, in read
>       data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
>       data = self.__fp.read(amt)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
>       n = self.readinto(b)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
>       n = self.fp.readinto(b)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
>       return self._sock.recv_into(b)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
>       return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
>       return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
>   socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
>       status = self.ruptions, args)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
>       return func(self, options, args)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py", line 332, in run
>       requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
>       discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
>       abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 314, in _get_abstract_dist_for
>       abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 410, in prepare_linked_requirement
>       local_file = unpack_url(
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 194, in unpack_url
>       file = get_http_url(
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 123, in get_http_url
>       from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 220, in _download_http_url
>       for chunk in download.chunks:
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 166, in iter
>       for x in it:
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\network\utils.py", line 15, in response_chunks
>       for chunk in response.raw.stream(
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 564, in stream
>       data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 529, in read
>       raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in **exit**
>       self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
>     File "c:\users\eduard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
>       raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
>   pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.

I tried even `easy_install watchdog` and got `The read operation timed out`. 
Some days earlier the pip was working, now it isn't. Other modules aren't installing too.
Please help me. What must I do??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDK IF THIS WILL WORK BUT HERE GOES.....

There is a big problem with the new version of pip that you might be  using. It's always better not to update pip to the new version.Use the version that gets installed with Python when you install it.

Uninstall pip and install it again.

```
pip uninstall pip
```

might work

Check this link to install pip 
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/

If this doesn't work , then reinstall Python and install pip through the installer and don't update it.And then try installing the required libraries....

Comment: Thank you !! It worked/ I deleted iand reinstalled it and it work!!

Comment: Your'e welcome! BTW this was my first solution I posted after joining recently on StackOverflow ! HAPPY TO HELP :)