# installing packages through pip in raspberry pi 3 model B (ReadTimeoutError)

Tags: python, pip, timeout, raspberry-pi3

I've been working on a project on my rpi 3 and I need to install some packages on it.
those being librosa, tensorflow, keras and kivy.
I am using python 3.7 with the most updated version of pip the os is raspbian.
when I started the project a few weeks ago and attempted to use pip to install those packages, everything worked fine, pip worked just as well as the pip on my desktop pc or laptop.
but yesterday and today whenever I try downloading any package from pip I keep getting the ReadTimeoutError over and over and nothing happens. even if something does happen it takes way too long and it shouldn't be that way.
I have access to the internet just fine. apt works fine when I download other packages not related to pip.
I've tried both WiFi and wired connection and it did not matter.

I am adding a screenshot of the shown error/warning

[image: error image]

Thanks in advance

edit: there's no traceback but just this warning that keeps repeating itself over and over.

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/tensorflow/
```

Comment: Please include tracebacks as text whenever possible

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port)

Comment: I've seen this post, increasing the timeout doesn't help me at all it just times out after 100 seconds instead.