# I tried to install "pyinstaller" with python 3.7.2

Tags: python, pyinstaller

**command:**

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

**Error:**

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pyinstaller/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pyinstaller/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pyinstaller/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pyinstaller/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pyinstaller/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyinstaller (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyinstaller
```

Comment: Which operating system are you on? Which python and which pip version do you use?

Comment: windows 10, python 3.7.2, 
pip 18.1 from c:\users\{USER}\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: try using , pip install --default-timeout=100 pyinstaller

Comment: I used pip install --default-timeout=100 pyinstaller and its happened again

Answer (score 0):

A similar question [How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port)

As suggested in the accepted answer of the above question you can use ,

```
pip install --default-timeout=100 pyinstaller
```

and if you are using python3 try using,

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

or

```
pip3 install --default-timeout=100 pyinstaller
```

if this does not solve problem try installing it as given in below question,

https://superuser.com/questions/1562975/install-pyinstaller-on-an-offline-computer

Comment: I downloaded the pyinstaller files, then what to do?

Comment: try this,  py -m pip install pyinstaller ,also check this - https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: @maor there is no specific tutorial or procedure listed to install the packages manually