# Can't install django project dependencies using pipenv install

Tags: python-3.x, django, pipenv, python-3.9, pipenv-install

I want to install Django project in fresh ubuntu 20.04.
The project requires python3.9, so I installed python3.9 using `sudo apt install python3.9 python3-pip` then I installed django using pip.

Now I want to install the project dependencies using `pipenv install`

here is the error I get:

```
mahdi@mahdi-Latitude-E6430:~/Desktop/Project1$ pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3.9 (3.9.5) to create virtualenv…
⠋created virtual environment CPython3.9.5.final.0-64 in 429ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/mahdi/.local/share/virtualenvs/Project1-UUOFIsQX, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, pkg_resources=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/mahdi/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

Virtualenv location: /home/mahdi/.local/share/virtualenvs/Project1-UUOFIsQX
Pipfile.lock (6ab9a1) out of date, updating to (5b3760)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 72, in resolve_hashes
    return {ireq: self.repository.get_hashes(ireq) for ireq in ireqs}
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 72, in <dictcomp>
    return {ireq: self.repository.get_hashes(ireq) for ireq in ireqs}
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 274, in get_hashes
    return {
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 275, in <setcomp>
    self._get_file_hash(candidate.location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 282, in _get_file_hash
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fp.read(8096), b""):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 282, in <lambda>
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fp.read(8096), b""):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 324, in read
    flush_decoder = True
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 237, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

**Pipfile**

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
asgiref = "==3.4.1"
psycopg2 = "==2.9.1"
pytz = "==2021.1"
sqlparse = "==0.4.2"
django-extensions = "==3.1.3"
Django = "==3.2.11"
Pillow = "==9.0.0"
pandas = "==1.3.2"
openpyxl = "==3.0.7"
factory-boy = "==3.2.0"
py-avataaars = "==1.1.2"
gunicorn = "==20.1.0"
django-heroku = "==0.3.1"
whitenoise = "==5.3.0"
django-webpack-loader = "==1.3.0"
et-xmlfile = "==1.1.0"
faker = "==8.12.0"
numpy = "==1.21.2"
python-dateutil = "==2.8.2"
six = "==1.16.0"
text-unidecode = "==1.3"
django-modeltranslation = "==0.17.3"
python-dotenv = "==0.19.2"
django-cors-headers = "==3.11.0"
django-hijack = "==3.1.4"
django-admin-honeypot = "==1.1.0"
django-axes = "==5.31.0"
xlsxwriter = "==3.0.2"

[dev-packages]
flake8 = "==4.0.1"

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

I have tried a lot of possible way, but could'nt find any solutions.

Comment: Maybe this wil help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43560499/16494437

Comment: Thanks @TrueGopnik, I tried this, but unfotunately it doesn't work!