# Install Opencv on Raspberry Pi 3b+ key error: opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I've been trying to install opencv on my raspberry pi 3b+ for few days using `pip3 install`. But it always ends up getting error like this. And for some reason it did manage to load over 50%,  but eventually the error occurred again.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/resolvelib-0.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 171, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = self.state.criteria[name]
KeyError: 'opencv-python'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 458, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 502, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out.
```

And another line of **another exception occurred** like the above but with bunches of url that ends with

```
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.piwheels.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

I hope u can help me

Comment: "Make sure that your pip version is up-to-date (19.3 is the minimum supported version)"

Comment: If the issue still persists after you have updated pip, please check the discussions on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43298872/18667225

Comment: @It_is_Chris mine is `pip 20.3.4`