# Error: couldn't find version that satisfied requirements docutils==0.16 and no matching distribution found for docutils

Tags: pip, version, python-3.10, docutils

While I was installing requirements.txt using: `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
I got this error

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/docutils/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement docutils==0.16 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for docutils==0.16
```

I tried downloading docutils alone using the command `pip install docutils` but it is still showing the same error. Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Please don't post (blurry and incomplete) pictures of a screen with an error message. Copy/paste the error message into your question, which makes it much more readable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port

Comment: This is a networking related issue. Have you tried `pip install --default-timeout=100 docutils`?

Comment: Yes ,I have tried this but it is still showing same error .I also tried downloading other modules like django with pip but it still showing this same error.

Comment: Are you in some kind of restricted network like a company or similar?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to install this in company's laptop.

Comment: You probably need to make some settings like proxy or similar. You should make a request with your IT department, because as I said, this is a networking related issue and your IT department are the ones that can give info about your companies network

Comment: I connected with other network and it worked.