# Exception occurred while installing jaxlib on Ubuntu x86_64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jax, google-ajax-libraries

I am unable to figure out how to troubleshoot these errors in `jaxlib` installation.
If somebody could please guide me on how to go about it, it will be much appreciated, Thanks. 
Below are the commands I am using with the corresponding outputs.

```
:~$ uname -a
Linux pc-name-15-3567 5.15.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 07:51:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

:~$ pip install --upgrade pip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (22.2.2)

:~$ pip install --upgrade "jax"
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: jax in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.3.17)
Collecting jax
  Downloading jax-0.3.19.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 221.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jax[cpu]) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: etils[epath] in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jax[cpu]) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from jax) (1.21.5)
Requirement already satisfied: opt_einsum in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jax[cpu]) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from jax) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing_extensions in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from jax[cpu]) (4.3.0)
Collecting jaxlib==0.3.15
  Downloading jaxlib-0.3.15-cp310-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (72.0 MB)
     ━━╺━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.1/72.0 MB 248.9 kB/s eta 0:04:33
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 435, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 516, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 90, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 465, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1273, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1129, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 369, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 373, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 213, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 204, in _get_updated_criteria
    self._add_to_criteria(criteria, requirement, parent=candidate)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 438, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 483, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 165, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 106, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 147, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 573, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 509, in read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/abbas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 440, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: There is a good answer to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got solved for me by running these commands to install jaxlib:

```
pip install --upgrade "jax"
pip install --upgrade "jaxlib"
```