# PySide2 on Windows11

Tags: windows, installation, pyside2

`Hello,
I tried to install PySide2 on windows by using: pip install PySide2.

And i have this:
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

Can you help me please ?

Thanks
Mahfoudh

T try to install PySide2 `

Comment: How did you installed python on your system? In my case, I use python 3.11 + PySide2 on windows 11, and it works just fine. However, I tried it (and did it just now to prove it) that if I use python installed from msys2 (ming64, the one I tried), the instalation doesn't work. For some reason there's some incompatibility to it. I found out that I could install PySide2 using the python for windows (found on the microsoft store). I recomend to check from which source you have installed your python application. That might be the cause of the error. If not, sorry, I can't help much.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue that the download for Pyside2 was timing out because it's over 100MB to download.

So I used the following extra arguments to install Pyside2 from the command line:

```
pip install PySide2 --default-timeout=100
```

See this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43560499/231860