Pip not installing any package
I have been trying to install django on my virtual environment using pip to learn creating websites, but whenever i try to install django using the command pip install django the terminal out put is the following:

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/1d/23/02f3795a71196019bcfec4c67890a6369e43b023474154fa0b2b7060346d/Django-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadataWARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/1d/23/02f3795a71196019bcfec4c67890a6369e43b023474154fa0b2b7060346d/Django-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadataWARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/1d/23/02f3795a71196019bcfec4c67890a6369e43b023474154fa0b2b7060346d/Django-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadataWARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/1d/23/02f3795a71196019bcfec4c67890a6369e43b023474154fa0b2b7060346d/Django-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadataWARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/1d/23/02f3795a71196019bcfec4c67890a6369e43b023474154fa0b2b7060346d/Django-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadataERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/1d/23/02f3795a71196019bcfec4c67890a6369e43b023474154fa0b2b7060346d/Django-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)"))

The result is an OSError. however I thought it would be better to show all the output.

I reinstalled python.
I tried to install it out of a virtual environment.
I tried to install it other packages to see if its django's fault.
I tried running the command on CMD, Powershell.

None of the following steps did work.

This issue is for a different package, but perhaps the issue for you is the same? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port

This might happen if you are behind proxy. You can tell pip to use specific proxy by using --proxy argument

pip install something --timeout=1000

Check your network connection. It is an error when pip sends http request to the server but the server does not respond within the time specified by pip.
You can try increasing the waiting time by doing the following:
pip install something --timeout=1000


So is an English-only site. Please translate the non-English text in your answer. Thanks

Try
 py -m pip install django

A timeout error usually means there is a network connection problems. Try connecting to a different service provider for installing packages.
