how to solve following warning:WARNING: Retrying... after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None,
redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org',
port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")':
/packages/b9/bf/663214a93a480c244f324e10be05afe59b0ec7ed5b018c9272c4e9ba6035/mathlib-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata

uninstall python 3.12.1 and installed again, also used another version 3.11 but still the problem is exsis.

Please check similar posts like https://stackoverflow.com/q/43298872/18667225. In a corporate network you may configure the corporate internet proxy.

This is a network issue. Your server/pc is not able to connect to pip to get the packages. Try changing your network or using a different pip mirror if the issue occurs on other network aswell.
